# How to set label and text field visible or invisible based on Radio Button in SAP UI app?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to display or hide the HBox based on the radio button.

if radio no is selected I want to display the hbox content otherwise hide it

Comment: SO is not a a code writing service. Please show us what you have already tried and what errors you are getting. Also please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what you are looking for:
https://jsbin.com/gekuno/3/edit?html,js,output.

In your view add to the radio button:

```
<RadioButton select="_handleSelect">
```

Then add the event handler to your controller:

```
_handleSelect: function(oEvent){
   var selected = oEvent.getSource().getSelected();
   var hbox = sap.ui.getCore().byId('hbox');

   hbox.setVisible(selected);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should try and comply with the MVC pattern and use Data Binding for both the HBox and RadioButtons.

Controller (bind model)

```js
let oObject = {
  selectedIndex: 1
};
let oModel = new JSONModel(oObject);
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "model");
```

View:

```html
<RadioButtonGroup selectedIndex="{model>/selectedIndex}">
  <buttons>
    <RadioButton text="Option 1"/>
    <RadioButton text="Option 2"/>
    <RadioButton text="Option 3"/>
  </buttons>
</RadioButtonGroup>

<HBox visible="{= {model>/selectedIndex} == 1 ? true : false}">
  ...
</HBox>
```

Above example would only show the HBox if the first RadioButton from the RadioButtonGroup is selected (which is true by default per object definition)